# PHP backend with JS xHTMLRequest frontend

Tags: javascript, php

In JS, I wanted to create a function that made a xHTMLRequest to a backend PHP server, problem is I want JS to wait for the response, otherwise it will display 'undefined'.

```
function xhrReq(method, args) {
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open(method, 'http://localhost/example/php/example.php');
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.send(args);
xhr.onreadystatechange = ()=> {
    if(xhr.readyState == 4) {
        return xhr.response;
    }
}
```

How can I make this function return the response value?

Comment: onreadystatechange will be called when the request has a final state, like 404, 200, 301 ecc ecc, so already you are qaiting for the response...

Comment: You don't _return_ the response.  Instead, you perform the action you want within the statechange callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) in a async function:

```
(async () => {
  try {
    //const args = ...;
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost/example/php/example.php', {
      method: 'POST', // or other
      headers,
      body: args
    });
  } catch (err) {
    //process error
  }
})()
```

or you can promisify your function :

```
function xhrReq(method, args) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open(method, 'http://localhost/example/php/example.php');
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.onload = function() {
      if (xhr.status === 200) {
        resolve(xhr.response);
      } else {
        reject(Error(`XHR request failed. Error code: ${xhr.statusText}`));
      }
    };
    xhr.onerror = function() {
      reject(Error('There was a network error.'));
    };
    xhr.send(args);
  });
}
```

And use it in a async function (or use promise) to get the response.

Comment: thanks, that helped, I got it to work with promises, but now that you mentioned, I'm actually keen in researching more about fetch API